# What does mean by "symlinks resolved" in the description of magic constant __FILE__?

Tags: php, constants, symlink, compile-time-constant, magic-constants

I'm using **PHP 7.2.0**

Below is a description of magic constant `__FILE__` :

> The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used
>   inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.

I didn't understand meaning of the clause **"filename of the file with symlinks resolved"**

Someone please make me understand the meaning of this clause with demonstrative suitable example of usage of magic constant `__FILE__` accompanied by appropriate explanation.

Comment: Sounds like PHP resolves the actual path of the symlink, rather than returning the symlinked path directly. I see you have tagged this question with `compile-time-constant`. There is no such thing in PHP.

Comment: @OptimusCrime : Please correct your facts. Here is the quote from the PHP manual itself : "All these "magical" constants are resolved at compile time, unlike regular constants thats resolved at runtime".

Comment: I am sorry, I was not aware of that. I have never heard anything about PHP having compile time constants, but I guess it makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symlinks (symbolic links) are "shortcuts" you can create in the filesystem to point one directory entry at any arbitrary other directory entry. On a *NIX shell, something like:

```
$ ln -s /foo/bar.php /baz
```

This establishes `/baz` as a symlink to `/foo/bar.php`. Whichever file you use now, they're effectively both the same.

*Resolving symlinks* means to look at a given path, recognise symlinks within it and replace them by the actual file path they point to. So, regardless of whether you do

```
$ php /baz
```

or

```
$ php /foo/bar.php
```

the `__FILE__` constant will be resolved to the actual file path `/foo/bar.php`.